# Simple/efficient text compression

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, text, compression

What's the simplest, but efficient compression algorithm?

Deflate, lzma, etc. aren't valid options. I need something that compiles really small, like: RLE, LZX, Huffman, etc..

Note: The data is 95% ASCII text
Edit: Data is ~20kb at the moment, but i expect it to grow up to 1mb

Edit2:
Other interesting options
smaz https://github.com/antirez/smaz
FastLZ http://fastlz.org/

Comment: How much text are you compressing? Compressing 12 chars is very different to 12Mb of chars.

Comment: Deflate is the canonical way of using Huffman... you're contradicting yourself there.

Comment: What kind of data are you compressing?  Device logs?  User journals?  What platform/device does this data live on?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like [LZO](http://www.oberhumer.com/opensource/lzo/) was designed to meet your requirements:

> - Decompression is simple and *very* fast.
> - Requires no memory for decompression.
> - Compression is pretty fast.

Comment: Works like a charm, compressed data size is ~58% of the original

Comment: Update: I made some optimizations on the file structure, now compressed size is ~40% of the original

Comment: Notice that it's license is GPL

Answer (score 3):

Something BWT-based would be probably good for this case.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burrows%E2%80%93Wheeler_transform
It compresses text much better than LZs, and is easy to implement from scratch,
and there're good libraries.
http://libbsc.com
http://encode.ru/threads/104-libBWT?p=22903&viewfull=1#post22903
http://code.google.com/p/libdivsufsort/

Or, alternatively, there's **ppmd** which is used for text compression in
rar/winzip/7-zip etc, but its more complicated.
http://www.compression.ru/ds/ppmdj1.rar
http://www.compression.ru/ds/ppmsj.rar (faster/small memory usage)
http://www.ctxmodel.net/files/PPMd/ppmd_Jr1_sh8.rar (alternative port)

Comment: Thanks, very interesting options, specially the BWT based.

Comment: However, LZma turns out better than the BWT-based bzip2.

Comment: On 900k+ files, maybe. But I didn't mention bzip2 anyway, and linked coders are better.

Answer (score 2):

you could try   http://scz-compress.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Looks really promising, i will definitely take a look.

Answer (score 2):

[This benchmark](http://cs.fit.edu/~mmahoney/compression/text.html) has a lot of comparisons. Check it out as it shows you also the algorithms used in the compression process.

Answer (score 1):

Most dictionary schemes will do nicely.  Any of the LZs.  We use an LZ77 varient on embedded systems for a lot of our simple compression stuff and it works beautifully with almost no memory overhead.  What kind of system is compressing and what is decompressing?  That will determine the type of compressor you can get away with.

Comment: I came across 2 very good implementations, http://src.opensolaris.org/source/xref/onnv/onnv-gate/usr/src/uts/common/os/compress.c and http://michael.dipperstein.com/lzw/ the first is really small and the compression is great